# why this query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by number order by number) as rn 
from (select t1.id as number,
             t1.name as name from #a as T1 
      join #a T2 on T1.id=T2.id)
```

why this query not working

it show error.....

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Missing alias name at the end. `..T1.id=T2.id ) a`

Comment: "PARTITION by number order by number" Doesn't make sense. Partition by the column or order by the column, not both.

Answer (score 3):

MSSQL requires that a derived table (subselect in the `from` clause) be [named](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/subqueries.php). Simply changing your query to:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by number order by number)as rn 
from 
(  
select t1.id as number,t1.name as name from  #a as T1  join #a T2 on T1.id=T2.id 
) subquery1
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: The proper term is `derived table` (which is a special form of a subquery). More info [here](https://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/derived-table-vs-subquery/).

Comment: @TT. And I thought that a "derived table" is the result of a table subquery?  Seems fine to give that thing in the FROM the name "subquery1".

Comment: @LukStorms I was not referring to the alias, just the term "subselect" he used in the first sentence.

Comment: @TT: Thanks for the tip.